# Bootstrap align header with data

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to create a static webpage (code below) but I am unable to align the +plus icon in header with the settings icon (glyphicon-cog) below. I tried everything from pull-right to padding but the plus icon refuses to budge. Any ideas on how to do it - I am looking for a clean responsive solution not quick fixes like adding padding or spaces.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container row">
        <div class="col-xs-1 hidden-xs">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <p class="navbar-text">
                    <a href="profile.html" class="navbar-link">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left glyphiconBackProperties default-blue"></span></a>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-10">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand default-blue" href="#">
                    Websites
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-1 hidden-xs">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <p class="navbar-text">
                    <a href="website-new.html" class="navbar-link">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus glyphiconPlusProperties default-blue"></span>
                    </a>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">
    <ul class="ul-wo-bullets">
        <li>
            <a href="page-list.html" class="blueColorText nounderline">Address Book App</a>
            <a href="website-edit.html">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog pull-right hidden-xs">
                      </span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="page-list.html" class="blueColorText nounderline" >Blogger</a>
            <a href="website-edit.html">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog pull-right hidden-xs">
                      </span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>

            <a href="page-list.html" class="blueColorText nounderline">Blogging App</a>
            <a href="website-edit.html">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog pull-right hidden-xs">
                      </span>
            </a>

        </li>
        <li>

            <a href="page-list.html" class="blueColorText nounderline">Script Testing App</a>
            <a href="website-edit.html">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog pull-right hidden-xs">
                      </span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>


<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom">
    <div class="container-fluid">

        <p class="navbar-text pull-right">
            <a href="profile.html" class="navbar-link">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user glyphiconUserProperties default-blue">
          </span>
            </a>
        </p>
    </div>
</nav>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you please provide a working [mcve] of your problem? Use the SO snippet tool or make a jsfiddle. Don't forget to put the contents of your `style.css` in the CSS box (otherwise I won't be able to see it).

Answer (score 0):

Use `.navbar-right` instead of `.pull-right` and remove `.row`. I also updated the markup to include one `<div class="navbar-header">` as I think it's intended to be used once in a Navbar and not multiple times.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-xs-1 hidden-xs">
      <p class="navbar-text">
        <a href="profile.html" class="navbar-link">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left glyphiconBackProperties default-blue"></span>
        </a>
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-10">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand default-blue" href="#">Websites</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-1 hidden-xs">
      <p class="navbar-text navbar-right">
        <a href="website-new.html" class="navbar-link">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus glyphiconPlusProperties default-blue"></span>
        </a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">
  <ul class="ul-wo-bullets">
    <li>
      <a href="page-list.html" class="blueColorText nounderline">Address Book App</a>
      <a href="website-edit.html">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog pull-right hidden-xs"></span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="page-list.html" class="blueColorText nounderline">Blogger</a>
      <a href="website-edit.html">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog pull-right hidden-xs"></span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>

      <a href="page-list.html" class="blueColorText nounderline">Blogging App</a>
      <a href="website-edit.html">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog pull-right hidden-xs"></span>
      </a>

    </li>
    <li>

      <a href="page-list.html" class="blueColorText nounderline">Script Testing App</a>
      <a href="website-edit.html">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog pull-right hidden-xs"></span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>


<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom">
  <div class="container-fluid">

    <p class="navbar-text pull-right">
      <a href="profile.html" class="navbar-link">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user glyphiconUserProperties default-blue">
          </span>
      </a>
    </p>
  </div>
</nav>
```

I removed `.row` form your Navbar because Bootstrap documentation doesn't have any examples using it. That's not to say you can't use `.row` in a Navbar but if you do use it be aware that `.row` has a `-15px` left and right margin which might mess with the alignment of the Navbar classes.

**Note:** The `.container` and `.row` classes of Bootstrap should be used on separate elements, see [Bootstrap Grid documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid).

Comment: Did not work.
Is there any reason we can't add container and row in same class?

Comment: My bad, it was working at a particular screen size but not others. I've updated my answer. As far as why you can't use `.container` and `.row` on the same element boils down to - that's not how the authors of Bootstrap made/intended them to work. It's all about how they set up their grid system.